# EF Core Going round in circles - multiple entity collection on various parents

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Have been spending a significant amount of time googling and searching for a resolution to this but not getting any closer.

I have a series of objects:

- Assumptions
- Dependencies
- Issues
- Risks
- Tasks
  ... etc (there are c15 object types)

At present they are all defined as simple classes at present - i will create the specifics of each later on:

```
public class ItemName
{
public Guid ItemNameId {get; set;}
public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

where `ItemName` is Assumption, Risk, Task etc...

These items can be 'owned by' a single consultancy, client, Programme, or Project

These are defined as:

```
public class ParentType
{
public Guid ParentTypeId {get; set;}
public virtual ICollection<Assumption> Assumptions {get; set;}
public virtual ICollection<dependency> Dependencies {get; set;}
public virtual ICollection<Issue> Issues {get; set;}
public virtual ICollection<Risk> Risks {get; set;}
public virtual ICollection<Task> Tasks {get; set;}
...remaining c10 Icollections
}
```

where `ParentType` is Consultancy, Client, Programme, Project.

I have defined all of these tables in DbContext

```
public DbSet<Assumption> Assumptions { get; set; }
public DbSet<Client> Clients { get; set; }
public DbSet<Consultancy> Consultancies { get; set; }
public DbSet<Dependency> Dependencies { get; set; }
public DbSet<Issue> Issues { get; set; }
public DbSet<Programme> Programmes { get; set; }
public DbSet<Project> Projects { get; set; }
public DbSet<Risk> Risks { get; set; }
public DbSet<Task> Tasks { get; set; }
```

How can I create the relationships in DbContext `OnModelCreating` method to create (for example) a collection of assumptions, dependencies, issues, risks and tasks on each of Consultancies, Clients, Programmes, and Projects.

I have tried so many intermediary table / hasone/hasmany code examples that I am now completelely lost... Really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like this would be a case for inheritance. EF Core supports TPH (Table-per-hierarchy) which should be fine for this purpose.  Rather than a "ParentType" table, define a base type to represent Consultancy, Client, Programme, and Project.. The entity, and table would contain all of these, and represent the FK for the relevant details like tasks etc.

I.e. ParentContainer

```
public abstract class ParentContainer
{
    [Key]
    public int ParentContainerId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Assumption> Assumptions {get; set;} = new List<Assumption>();
    public virtual ICollection<Dependency> Dependencies {get; set;} = new List<Dependency>();
    public virtual ICollection<Issue> Issues {get; set;} = new List<Issue>();
    public virtual ICollection<Risk> Risks {get; set;} = new List<Risk>();
    public virtual ICollection<Task> Tasks {get; set;} = new List<Task>();
    // ...
}
```

Then the concrete classes:

```
public class Company : ParentContainer
{}

public class Client : ParentContainer
{}

public class Programme : ParentContainer
{}

public class Project : ParentContainer
{}
```

These can be configured with a Discriminator, either a string or something like an enumeration (Int) so that ParentContainer records would contain a column to indicate whether they were a Client or a Programme, etc.

The limitation of this approach is that TPH means that all columns for the different "types" are ultimately contained within the same table. This means if you have various different columns that apply to a client vs. a programme, these would all end up as null-able columns on the ParentContainer table. To help avoid this if you need any significant number of additional columns for one or more types I would recommend adopting a composition model. Properties that are common to all types such as "Name" would reside in the ParentContainer table. The type-specific would be moved into a type-specific details table.

For example, a Company and Client might have an Address, while Programme and Project don't. A programme and project may have a Coordinator.. Each may have a number of very specific fields. We can do this:

```
public class Company : ParentContainer
{
    public string AddressLine1 { get; set; } // Could simply be AddressId, for demonstration purposes...
    public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string PostCode { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; } 
}

public class Client : ParentContainer
{
    public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string PostCode { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
}

public class Programme : ParentContainer
{
    public virtual Person Coordinator { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
}

public class Project : ParentContainer
{
    public virtual Person Coordinator { get; set; }
    public string ProjectCriteria { get; set;}
}
```

However what would end up happening is that all of these fields would need to be added as null-able columns to the ParentContainer table. The composition model would see something more like:

```
public class Company : ParentContainer
{
   public virtual CompanyDetails Details { get; set; }
}

public class Client : ParentContainer
{
  public virtual ClientDetails Details { get; set; }
}

public class Programme : ParentContainer
{
    public virtual ProgrammeDetails Details { get; set; }
}

public class Project : ParentContainer
{
    public virtual ProjectDetails Details { get; set; }
}

public class CompanyDetails
{
    [Key]
    public int CompanyDetailsId { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine1 { get; set; } // Could simply be AddressId, for demonstration purposes...
    public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string PostCode { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; } 
}

public class ClientDetails
{
    [Key]
    public int ClientDetailsId { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string PostCode { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
}

public class ProgrammeDetails
{
    [Key]
    public int ProgrammeDetailsId { get; set; }
    public virtual Person Coordinator { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
}

public class ProjectDetails
{
    [Key]
    public int ProjectDetailsId { get; set; }
    public virtual Person Coordinator { get; set; }
    public string ProjectCriteria { get; set;}
}
```

This would see the ParentContainer class contain 4 null-able FKs for the 4 details references alongside any "common" columns. The type specific fields are in the details tables. This allows these columns to be required vs. optional at your discretion, and you can also use the applicable *DetailsId as a FK to other one-to-many or many-to-many relationships between other tables and one of the specific types rather than the ParentContainer. This technically forms a many-to-one relationship between the ParentContainer and the details, and there is technically nothing stopping multiple containers referencing the same Detail row, or more than one of the details. That limitation needs to be enforced by the application, and you can use health check queries to detect any illegal deviations. (due to bugs or incorrect data-side updates)

The catch of using this approach is that you'll end up having a DbSet of ParentContainers rather than Company vs. Client etc. Your repositories/services can mitigate this and return the concrete instances by leveraging `OfType<T>` as part of the querying. For instance, to get a list of Companies with names starting with "N":

```
var query = context.ParentContainers
    .OfType<Company>()
    .Where(x => x.Name.StartsWith("N"));
```

This allows you to access the type-specific details as well:

```
var query = context.ParentContainers
    .OfType<Company>()
    .Where(x => x.CompanyDetails.Address.City == "New York");
```

Comment: Thanks Steve, that worked really well and a million times simpler than where I had ended up.

Comment: Is there a way to add a collection of users to each of the entities (parent entities company, client etc and  each of the child entities assumption, dependencies etc) with a marker for their access level  (view edit delete etc). I have a User object {[Key]Guid UserId, string Name etc} and a simple enum UserAccessType with the access level strings. The many to many relationship examples I have found need reciprocal entities on both sides of the join but in this instance the user side would remain as user but the reciprocal side could be company, project, risk, task etc... is this feasible?